# Can't create a bootstrap nested grid system

Tags: html, css, grid, bootstrap-5

I'm having troubles trying to create a grid layout like this

[Grid layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvISS.png)

what i assumed was to create a row and have 2 columns divided, and create a row+col inside each of the 2 columns and in each col have a card.

this is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      Modules
      <div class="module-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
              <div class="card-body">
                title
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
              <div class="card-body">
                title
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
              <div class="card-body">
                title
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                <div class="card-body">
                  title
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                <div class="card-body">
                  title
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                <div class="card-body">
                  title
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          

        
   <div class="col-4">
      Schedule
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/images/star.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
            <div class="card-body">
              title
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/images/star.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
            <div class="card-body">
              title
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

and this is what came out
[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDgk4.png)

I dont understand why the cards in my second row aren't the same length too?

Comment: Can you share all your html code, I am missing something, the first columns are only two, then comes one line. The first three are not complete. Or better way is to build that in stackblitz and share the project there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add outer row and add 2 columns and then inside first column add row then give your columns col-3, col-4 how much you want in a row same goes to second column. I hope down script help you

```html
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- outer grid first column -->
            <div class="col-8">
                Modules
                <div class="module-container">
                    <!-- first column inner grid  -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="/images/pat.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    title
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- outer grid second column -->
            <div class="col-4">
                Schedule
                <!-- second column inner grid  -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="/images/star.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                title
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="/images/star.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="module 1">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                title
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ohhh yeah the comments are super helpful thank you, can i ask what is mt-2 for? i realize some of the columns has but not all

Comment: mt-2 means margin-top